# How Failover works when Primary VM Set get restarted?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-load-balancer

[image]

Above is sample configuration for Azure Service Fabric.

1. I have created with Wizard and I have deployed one Asp.net core Application and  that I am able to access from out side.
2. Now if you look at the image below Service Fabric is being access with sfclustertemp.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com. I am able to access application with 
   sfclustertemp.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/api/values.
3. Now if I restart primary VM set it should transfer load to secondary and I have a thought that it should done automatically but it is not as Second Load Balancer has different dns name. ( If I specify different dns name then it is accessible).

I have understanding cluser has one id so it is common for both load balancer.

Is such configuration possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [Azure Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring) with health probes.

However, instead of using multiple node types for fail-over options during reboot, have a look at '[Durability tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity)'. Using Silver or Gold will have the effect that reboots are performed sequentially on machine groups (grouped by fault domain), instead of all at once.

> The durability tier is used to indicate to the system the privileges
>   that your VMs have with the underlying Azure infrastructure. In the
>   primary node type, this privilege allows Service Fabric to pause any
>   VM level infrastructure request (such as a VM reboot, VM reimage, or
>   VM migration) that impact the quorum requirements for the system
>   services and your stateful services.

Answer (score 1):

There is misconception on what is a SF cluster.

On your diagram, the part you describe on the left as 'Service Fabric' does not belong there.

Service Fabric is nothing more than applications and services deployed in the cluster nodes, when you create a cluster, you define a ***primary node type***, will be there where service fabric will deployed the services used for managing the cluster.

A node type will be formed by:

- A VM Scale Set: machines with OS and SF services installed
- A load balancer with dns and IP, forwarding requests to the VM Scale Set

So what you describe there, should be represented as:

```
NodeTypeA (Primary)
    Load Balancer (cluster domain + IP)
        VM Scale Set
            SF management services (explorer, DNS)
            Your applications
NodeTypeB
    Load Balancer (other dns + IP)
        VM Scale Set
            Your applications
```

Given that:

- the first concern is, if the Primary Node goes down, you will lose your cluster, because the management services won't be available to manage your service instances.
- second: you shouldn't rely on node types for this kind of reliability, you should increase the reliability of your cluster adding more nodes to the node types.
- third: if the concern is a data center outage, you could:

  - Create a custom cluster that [span multiple regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions#can-i-create-a-cluster-that-spans-multiple-azure-regions-or-my-own-datacenters)
  - Add a reverse proxy or API gateway in front of your service to route the request wherever your service is.